How can I make last page of a print preview take up full page
Please, I am trying to convert HTML to pdf, when the page is more than one page, the last page don't take up all the page but just stop at the div. How can I make sure the css content like background colors go all the way down.enter image description here
I want to make the left and right div colors go all the way down on the last page. And if possible, add some padding to the last page.
For context, I am using puppeteer to convert html to pdf.
This is my html code. (it will be converted to a handlesbar template)
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Blinker&display=swap"
    />

<style>
  html {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    width: 21cm;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Blinker', sans-serif;
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .leftPanel {
    width: 27%;
    background-color: #405544;
    padding: 0.7cm;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .rightPanel {
    width: 73%;
    padding: 0.7cm;
  }

  page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    position: relative;
  }

  page[size="A4"] {
    width: 21cm;
  }

  @page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0mm;
    border: none;
  }

  img {
    width: 4cm;
    height: 4cm;
    margin-bottom: 0.7cm;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
  }

  .user-name {
    color: #405544;
    font-weight: semibold;
    font-size: 1.2cm;
    border-bottom: black 6px solid;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: 'Blinker', sans-serif;
  }

  .section-title-right {
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.4cm;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 1cm;
    margin-bottom: 0.2cm;
  }

  .text {
    color: #353c44;
    font-size: 0.3cm;
  }

  .with-line {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 0.8cm;
  }

  .section-details {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .job-title, .job-company, .education-title, .education-school {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
  }

  .job-title {
    margin-bottom: 0.07cm;
  }

  .job-description {
    margin-top: 0.3cm;
    padding-left: 0.3cm;
  }

  .job-description li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-bottom: 0.1cm;
  }

  .job-item, .education-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.2cm;
  }

  .education-details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .p-left-small {
    padding-left: 2px;
  }

  .p-right-small {
    padding-right: 2px;
  }

  page:last-of-type .leftPanel,
  page:last-of-type .rightPanel {
    min-height: 29.7cm;
  }

  @media print {
    /* Specify page size */
    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0;
      height: 29.7cm;
    }
    
    /* Add page break after each page */
    page {
      page-break-after: always;
      min-height: 29.7cm;
      /* Change background color as needed */
      display: block;
    }
    
    /* Hide overflowing content on additional pages */
    page:last-of-type {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    /* Adjust leftPanel and rightPanel to have minimum height of 29.7cm */
    page .leftPanel, page .rightPanel {
      min-height: 29.7cm;
    }
    
    /* Adjust the height of the last page to fill the remaining space */
    page:last-of-type::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      
    }
  }
</style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <page size="A4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="leftPanel">
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633332755192-727a05c4013d?w=800&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dXNlcnxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D"
          />
          <div class="details">
            <div class="item bottomLineSeparator">
              <h2>
                CONTACT
              </h2>
              <div class="smallText">
                <p>
                  <i class="fa fa-phone contactIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  (+33) 777 777 77
                </p>
                <p>
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope contactIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <a href="lorem@ipsum.com@gmail.com">
                    lorem@ipsum.com
                  </a>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <i
                    class="fa fa-map-marker contactIcon"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  ></i>
                  New York, USA
                </p>
                <p>
                  <i
                    class="fa fa-linkedin-square contactIcon"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  ></i>
                  <a href="#">
                    in/loremipsum
                  </a>
                </p>
                <p class="lastParagrafNoMarginBottom">
                  <i class="fa fa-skype contactIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <a href="#">
                    loremipsum
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item bottomLineSeparator">
              <h2>
                SKILLS
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h2>
                EDUCATION
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightPanel">
          <section>
            <h1 class="user-name">
              John Doe
            </h1>
          </section>

          <section>
            <h1 class="section-title-right">Professional Summary</h1>
            <p class="text">Practical, highly skilled individual demonstrating
              out-of-the-box thinking. Optimises cost-effective operations and
              improves safety by scrutinising existing practices. Proven success
              fulfilling complex project briefs on-time and under budget.</p>

          </section>

          <section>
            <h1 class="section-title-right with-line">Work history</h1>

            <div class="job-item">
              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <div>
                    <p class="job-title text">Software engineer</p>
                    <p class="text"><span class="job-company">Google</span>
                      <span>- Longcot, Oxford</span></p>
                  </div>

                  <p class="text"><span>04/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>

                </div>

                <ul class="job-description text">
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>

                </ul>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <div>
                    <p class="job-title text">Software engineer</p>
                    <p class="text"><span class="job-company">Google</span>
                      <span>- Longcot, Oxford</span></p>
                  </div>

                  <p class="text"><span>04/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>

                </div>

                <ul class="job-description text">
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>

                </ul>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <div>
                    <p class="job-title text">Software engineer</p>
                    <p class="text"><span class="job-company">Google</span>
                      <span>- Longcot, Oxford</span></p>
                  </div>

                  <p class="text"><span>04/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>

                </div>

                <ul class="job-description text">
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>

                </ul>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <div>
                    <p class="job-title text">Software engineer</p>
                    <p class="text"><span class="job-company">Google</span>
                      <span>- Longcot, Oxford</span></p>
                  </div>

                  <p class="text"><span>04/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>

                </div>

                <ul class="job-description text">
                  <li>Maintained project momentum by providing detailed progress
                    reports and milestone updates to key stakeholders.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Implemented software performance monitoring tools,
                    identifying and resolving bottlenecks.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Oversaw new feature updates to existing software systems to
                    add functionality.</li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

          </section>

          <section>
            <h1 class="section-title-right with-line">Education</h1>
            <div class="education-item">
              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <p class="text education-title">Bachelors of Science,
                    <span class="text">Computer Science</span></p>
                  <p class="text"><span>02/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="education-details">
                  <p class="education-school text p-right-small">University of
                    Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small p-right-small">Logincot, Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small">Merit</p>

                </div>

              </div>

              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <p class="text education-title">Bachelors of Science,
                    <span class="text">Computer Science</span></p>
                  <p class="text"><span>02/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="education-details">
                  <p class="education-school text p-right-small">University of
                    Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small p-right-small">Logincot, Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small">Merit</p>

                </div>

              </div>

              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <p class="text education-title">Bachelors of Science,
                    <span class="text">Computer Science</span></p>
                  <p class="text"><span>02/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="education-details">
                  <p class="education-school text p-right-small">University of
                    Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small p-right-small">Logincot, Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small">Merit</p>

                </div>

              </div>

              <div>
                <div class="section-details">
                  <p class="text education-title">Bachelors of Science,
                    <span class="text">Computer Science</span></p>
                  <p class="text"><span>02/2022</span>
                    -
                    <span>10/2024</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="education-details">
                  <p class="education-school text p-right-small">University of
                    Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small p-right-small">Logincot, Oxford</p>
                  -
                  <p class="text p-left-small">Merit</p>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

          </section>

        </div>

      </div>
    </page>

  </body>
</html>

This is my puppeteer implementation
export async function generatePDFFromHTML(
  htmlContent: string,
  outputPath: string
): Promise<void> {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setContent(htmlContent);

  await page.pdf({
    path: outputPath,
    format: "A4",
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    printBackground: true,
    margin: {
      top: "0.4in",
      bottom: "0.4in",
      left: "0.4in",
      right: "0.4in",
    },
  });

  await browser.close();
}


Just curious why the CSS is minified. You might want to unminify it if it's relevant and not autogenerated.
